# Enhance image in matlab - exp operation - imageJ software-LPR

Tags: image-processing, matlab, enhancement

I use imageJ software, imageJ has a EXP command (process >math >exp ).

original image:

[image: http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00594/x1tlq1q839bc.png]

output image processed by EXP command in imageJ software:

[image: http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00594/7znj3tzvefui.png]

in this link explain how do that ImageJ: http://imagej.1557.x6.nabble.com/Process-gt-Math-gt-Exp-td5009733.html

How can I do that in matlab?

It is the matlab code which I wrote,Please correct my mistakes.

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;
img=imread('http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00594/fdg3933aznwz.jpg');
im=rgb2gray(img);
im=im2double(im);

figure,imshow(im)

    for i=1:size(im,1)
        for j=1:size(im,2)

          in = (im(i,j)+1);
          result(i,j) = 255*exp(in/46.01);

        end
    end
figure,imshow(mat2gray(result))
```

Comment: dear @SergV   the second image is this: http://s6.uplod.ir/i/00594/7znj3tzvefui.png

you put the first image instead of first and second image.
please edit it.thanks alot

Comment: I change image by your request. Wait some time. But it was not my fault - maybe it was  a some failure. Good luck.

Comment: You provide a link which describes very clear this function. What's your trouble? Could you give source in Matlab, with which you have tried to solve the problem?

Comment: Dear  @SergV  I added my source code :) , please help me and correct my mistakes. thanks alot again. and thanks for your time. (v)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to learn to debug your programs. Try formula for some data:

```
>> 255*exp(255/46.01)
  ans =   6.5091e+004
```

So formula has bug (explanation in link to forum is valid. Read it carefully). Valid formula:

```
>> exp(255/46.01)
 ans =  255.26
```

But try calculation with real data from your image:

```
>> in = (im(10,10)+1)
in = 254
>> exp(in/46.01)
ans =  403.43    % very strange result!!!!
>> in/46.01
ans = 6          %what is it????
```

Reason is quite simple - type of **in** is *uint8*!!!

Valid formula:

```
result(i,j) = exp(double(in)/46.01);
```

result:

```
imshow(uint8(result));
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @SergV ,I do appreciate you for what you have done for me.